# WebContainer vs webserver vs servlet container

Tags: java, servlets, webserver

I have studied that "Web Container" is a part of a "Web Server".

But,my doubt is,

> 1) If  the  "Web Container" is a combination of Servlet Container and JSP Engine

If it is  correct,what is the role of web Server,web container,Servlet container and  JSP engine.?

or

> 2) If the "Web Container" is only a Servlet Container.

If it is correct,what is the role of web server,web container.And what about jsp pages execution.?

Comment: Do you know that JSP scripts are converted to Servlets (which could be run by container)?

Comment: I know that,Jsp scrpits are converted to servlets.But,I think Jsp engine convert this.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/overview.htm) see if it adds to your understanding. Basically there are different containers available that perform different functions in the Java EE spec.